# How to use javascript to add form.action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am building django website, and have to use some select submit,my codes are:

```
<form id='buttonform1' method='get'>
   <div class="control-group btn">           
            <div class="controls "> 
              <select id="select01"> 
                <option>2017</option> 
                <option>2018</option> 
                <option>2019</option> 
                <option>2020</option>               
              </select> 

              <select id="select02"> 
                <option>1</option> 
                <option>2</option> 
                <option>3</option> 
                <option>5</option>               
                <option>6</option>               
                <option>7</option>               
                <option>8</option>               
                <option>9</option>               
                <option>10</option>               
                <option>11</option>               
                <option>12</option>         
              </select>             
            <input type="button" value='submit' id='submit1'> 
</div> </div> 
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#submit1").click(function(){   
  var year=$('#select01').val(); 
  var month=$('#select02').val(); 
  var action1="?year="+year+"&month="+month 
    alert(action1);      
   document.getElementById('buttonform1').action=action1; 
   document.getElementById('buttonform1').submit();  

}); 
}) 
</script>
```

the alert message is:

```
 ?year=2017&month=1
```

But submit result lost the action information:

```
http://localhost/report/?
```

If i change the action like this(delete '?'):

```
var action1="year="+year+"&month="+month
```

the result is:

```
http://localhost/report/year=2017&month=1?
```

What else can i do? thx

Comment: This is a very odd way to use a form. Why not just set the `action` attribute on the `form` directly in the HTML, set the correct `name` attributes on your `select` elements and then `submit` it as normal?

Comment: Thank you! I'm a newbie, could you give more details in codes?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather odd way to use a `form`. You can achieve what you require in HTML alone, without any JS interference.

Firstly set the `action` attribute of the form to the URL that data should be sent to. Then you can add `name` attributes to the `select` elements so that the values are keyed correctly. Finally, change the button to a `submit` so that the form information gets sent when it's clicked. Try this:

```html
<form id="buttonform1" action="your-page-here.html" method="get">
  <div class="control-group btn">
    <div class="controls">
      <select id="select01" name="year"> 
        <option>2017</option> 
        <option>2018</option> 
        <option>2019</option> 
        <option>2020</option>               
      </select>

      <select id="select02" name="month"> 
        <option>1</option> 
        <option>2</option> 
        <option>3</option> 
        <option>5</option>               
        <option>6</option>               
        <option>7</option>               
        <option>8</option>               
        <option>9</option>               
        <option>10</option>               
        <option>11</option>               
        <option>12</option>         
      </select>

      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit1">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: the name can add to select directly!! hahaha~ what a fool i am.
It's useful! Thx.
And i still want to know the form.action issue, because i need use it somewhere else.